# $f(x) = x$ or a , if $f(x)$ and $a$ is known find $x$ boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am new to boolean algebra. I am facing difficulty solving this problem:

> Given $f(x) = x \lor a$, for some $f(x)$ and $a$, deduce the value of $x$.

Can someone provide me the solution with example?

Similarly, if $p(x) = x \land a$ for some $p(x)$ and $a$, how can I deduce $x$?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about sets: if $Y=X\cap A$ or $Y=X \cup A$, then there are *many* solutions for $X$ given $A$ and $Y$

Comment: Can you tell me the number of probable solution ? Assume x is n bit in length.

Answer (score 0):

If $Y=X \cup A$ then obviously $A \subseteq Y$.

For every subset $R \subseteq A$ the disjoint union $X:=R \cup (Y\setminus A)$ is a solution of $Y=X \cup A$, so there are $2^{\#A}$ solutions